# microphone setting changes when the sound control panel is closed

Tags: 14.04

I select which microphone to use in the sound control panel, but I must leave the sound control panel open in order to use the selected microphone because when I close the sound control panel, the other microphone is automatically selected. Is there a way to prevent this problem so I may talk while doing other control panel functions?

Comment: Depends. What application, what mic ? You may have better luck with jack

Comment: Application? The only application or program I am using is the sound control panel. I open the sound control panel, select the microphone of choice, close the control panel, open the control panel to find that the microphone selected has been deselected.

What Microphone? Headset and webcam microphones are the choices. For most work I prefer the webcam microphone, but that selection will revert to the headset microphone when the sound control panel closes. Both are USB.

Comment: Same here. Any solution other than keeping control panel open?